# Visual Studio 2017's Team Explorer not remembering a server

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I jump between several different source control server, and there's one that Visual Studio refuses to remember.  Whenever I open VS2017, it remembers two .visualstudio.com repositories and one LAN-located TFS server, but I can't figure out why this specific VSO repo is never remembered.

Any ideas for me to try?  Perhaps there's a limit on the number of connections that get remembered (unlikely) or there's a config file somewhere that's getting cached.

Comment: Do you mean VS team explorer not remember a VSTS account or just not remember a repo in a VSTS account?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Both.  I connect to a repo in a VSTS account, it loads the branches, but when I go back to the Connections pane, the account (and repo) that I had just connected to are not listed.  If I restart Visual Studio, I must re-add the account/repo.

Comment: Does the cloned git repo exist under the local repositories (https://ibb.co/eQdOpy)?

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Yes, it's under local instead of the connections above.

Comment: Please try with below steps: 1. remove the credential for the VSTS account in Credential Manager -> Windows Credentials; 2. Clean VS cach in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache`; 3. Connect the VSTS in VS and clone the repo again; 4. Restart VS to check if the VSTS account and the repo can be remembered.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Clearing the cache doesn't seem to have done anything.  When I opened VS, all the same connections immediately populated.  Finishing the instructions didn't change anything.

Comment: If the certain VSTS account/repo always can not remembered in team explorer, you can also report the issue in https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html.